# Kafka not passing message when gdb attached to the consumer program

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm new to Kafka. I have a program sending message to Kafka, and one program receiving the message. Everything works fine until I tried to use debugger(gdb in this case) to attach to the receiving process. Once I set a breakpoint, the receiving program won't receive messages anymore. I tried to increase the retention.ms and session.timeout.ms, all doesn't work. The kafka logs show me that it keep trying to rebalance group. Not sure if anyone has any clue on this. Thanks.

Comment: Does your breakpoint prevents a consumer from sending heartbeats back to the coordinator by any chance?

Comment: I'm not quiet sure. I set the breakpoint in the function that listen to the message